# Send email from React Native using SMTP protocol

Tags: react-native, email, smtp, expo

I want to press a button, and send myself an email with a Gmail account, using SMTP protocol in an Expo app in React Native.
I don't want to use `Linking`, because it opens a Gmail screen, and I want to send the email with code, not to make the user send it.

I found a module called `react-native-smtp-mailer` but it throws me an error I couldn't solve.

This is the function I've made:

```
import RNSmtpMailer from "react-native-smtp-mailer";

export async function sendEmail() {
  const res = await RNSmtpMailer.sendMail({
    mailhost: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: "465",
    ssl: true,
    username: "get.food.cordoba@gmail.com",
    password: "password123",
    from: "get.food.cordoba@gmail.com",
    recipients: "octaviopercivaldi2@gmail.com",
    subject: "subject 123",
    htmlBody: "<p>body 123</p>",
    attachmentPaths: [],
    attachmentNames: [],
    attachmentTypes: [],
  })
  console.log(res)
}
```

This is what I got from running the `sendEmail` function:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeSmtpMailer.default.sendMail')]
```

If you know any other solution, or if you know how to make this module works, let me know, please.
Thank for the answers.

Comment: Disclaimer: Not a solution for the above issue. I have had a similar requirement 2 months back and I did try the same and was not able to achieve with any solution and finalized left the approach went with API based email. And that is more preferable as well because for SMTP to connect you need to either share the password via API or hardcode the same in the mobile app, either way, it is not secure than calling an API. one more solution is using third party solution AWS SNS or SendGrid or Sentry.

Answer (score 2):

The library you are trying to use `https://github.com/angelos3lex/react-native-smtp-mailer` requires a bare react-native project, to use this library you need to eject from the expo project to do this run this command in the project's root directory:

```
expo-cli eject
```

Then installing `react-native-smtp-mailer` using `npm` or `yarn`

Then running `react-native link react-native-smtp-mailer`

Then following these extra steps:
https://github.com/angelos3lex/react-native-smtp-mailer#extra-steps

Run `yarn ios` or `yarn android` to start the JavaScript bundler server and build the project binary. This requires Xcode or Android Studio, depending on the platform.

However this is not the best way to send an email, eventually you'll need to implement a server api where you send your message through, which is more secure, or use a web service such as AWS email service.

Comment: If anyone is able to get this library working with latest versions of React Native (I'm on 0.64.2), let me know. I cannot build my app after linking this library (testing with iOS).

Answer (score 1):

If you're from the future and having the same problem as me, you could try:

1. The solution given by kareem adel
2. This solution I've found:

I didn't want to eject, so I searched for another alternatives.
And I found the **Firebase Cloud Functions**, they're just like a backend that runs 24/7, free, with a Google Firebase project. The good thing about that, is that you can use NodeJS, and the `nodemailer` library to send emails (and do everything you can think off).

Here it is a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@edigleyssonsilva/cloud-functions-for-firebase-sending-e-mail-1f2631d1022e) I found very very usefull in Medium.

Comment: warning: costs money...`Error: Your project MyProject must be on the Blaze (pay-as-you-go) plan to complete this command.` (after running `firebase deploy`)